# Java - Execute a .SH file

Tags: java, runtime

How would I go about executing a .SH file (this is localhost, no remote connection or anything)? I've seen lots of `Runtime.exec` and other things when I searched but those didn't seem to work.

This is Java 6. Also if it matters, all the SH is doing is moving two folders around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myshell.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Process p = pb.start();
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
 String line = null;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
 {
    System.out.println(line);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also give some consideration to the [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) if you do not want to make your code platform-dependent by directly invoking OS commands.