# How can I execute linux terminal command from java?

Tags: java, linux, sh

I want to automatically change the ip address of an Ubuntu 12.04 PC by a program fires at startup. For some certain reasons, I want to code it in Java.

Exactly the solution is written here:

[Java - Execute a .SH file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422869/java-execute-a-sh-file)

But it does not work in my case. I could not manage to find why,essentially my case is a special case of so called thread, I try to run a sudo-command in linux with

```
public static void executeCommandLine(String strCommand){
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process p = rt.exec(strCommand);
        if(p==null){
            System.out.println("Error in process");
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = null;
         try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
             {
                System.out.println(line);
             }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call this executeCommandLine() function from another function as follows:

```
public static void changeIpAddress(String strIpAddress, String strRootPassword, String strEthDevice){
    String strCommandLine = "";

    if(PLATFORM == PLATFORM_LINUX){
        strCommandLine =  "/bin/echo " + strRootPassword +  "| sudo -S /sbin/ifconfig " + strEthDevice + " " + strIpAddress;
    }else if(PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS){
        // TODO: Write for Windows
    }else{
        System.out.println("OS not supported");
    }

    System.out.println("Executed command:");
    System.out.println(strCommandLine);

    executeCommandLine(strCommandLine);
}
```

Comment: do you receive any error or what is not working?

Comment: No, I did not, but I receive the following output, and when I check the ip address, it is not configured:

/bin/echo mypass | sudo -S /sbin/ifconfig usb0 192.168.0.99
mypass | sudo -S /sbin/ifconfig usb0 192.168.0.99
Especially, it seems like the system echoes the part starting from "mypass". However when I run the line from the terminal, the ip is changed

Comment: Please add that code which calls `executeCommandLine()` to your question, including the code which sets up the actual command that you're trying to run. Also, please describe exactly what happens when `executeCommandLine()` runs. Is there an error message?

Comment: @Kenster it is allready there? changeIpAdress(...) calls executeCommandLine(strCommandLine). It seems that the code is working, but the command is not executed (Maybe I didn't understand it correctly, quite hard to mention what the questionar whants..) I'm not a linux expert, but maybe remove the /bin/echo/ ?

Comment: Sorry about that, I don't know what I was thinking.